# How do i set full height on a component in a scroll view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a web developer trying to learn  SwiftUI and have some questions regarding about my issue.

So my code architecture is as follows:

ContentView.swift

```
ScrollView(.vertical){
      Foreach(users){
   user in UserCard()
  }
}
```

UserCard.swift

```
VStack(){
 Image()
 Text("long text")
}
```

How do I make my UserCard to always the height of my iphone? As of right now, my UserCard sometimes overflow or cuts off too quickly depending on my Text length.

Any help would be appreciated. And any tips for a SwiftUI beginner would be great!

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Would you add screenshot of problem layout which you want to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be full screen and ignoring safe area you can set the `UserCard`'s height to screen height like this:

```
VStack(){
   Image()
   Text("long text")
}
.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

And if you want it to respect safe area you could use a `GeometryReader`:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ScrollView {
        Color.red
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
        Color.blue
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
        Color.yellow
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
one Question -> one Answer
```

for second part of your Question need new Question with own Topic.

```
    ZStack()
    {

        VStack()
        {
            Image(systemName: "star")
            Text("long text")
        }
        
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
```